# XPath union elements under an ancestor element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Xpath to find span and div elements under an ancestor element.

```
ancestor_element
    ---------------//span
    ---------------//div
    ---------------//input
```

Suppose the xpath is  a_very_complex_xpath_to_find_the_ancestor_element for the ancestor_element. It is very complex.

```
(a_very_complex_xpath_to_find_the_ancestor_element//span) | (a_very_complex_xpath_to_find_the_ancestor_element//div)
```

The above union slows down the performance greatly. Is there a better Xpath for union? Tried the following:

```
a_very_complex_xpath_to_find_the_ancestor_element//(span | div)
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need little tweak to your xpath.

```
a_very_complex_xpath_to_find_the_ancestor_element//*[local-name()='span' or local-name()='div']
```

Here we are finding the elements based on the tag name either span or div.

```html
<html><head></head><body>
      <div id="ancestor">
      <a>
          <label>inner</label>
         </a>
     <span> span under ancestor </span>
     <label> label under ancestor </label>
     <div> div under ancestor </div>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

[image]

Comment: Works for Chrome. Just tried Firefox, it did not work.

Comment: Ok, all you have to do change `name()` to use `local-name()`. Updated the answer.